# How to clearTimeout this function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, settimeout, cleartimeout

How to clearTimeout this function ?

This is my code, i tried but not work.

How can i do ?

.............................................................................................................................................................

```
<form id="fid">
    <input type="text" id="input_type" onkeypress="stop()" onkeyup="run()"/>
</form>

    <p id="myplace"></p>

    <script>
    function run() {
        $('#myplace').hide();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.ajax
            (
                {
                    url: 'xx.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $('#fid').serialize(),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#myplace').show();
                        $('#myplace').html(data);
                    }
                }
            )
        }, 3000);
    }

    function stop() {
        clearTimeout();    
    }    
    </script>
```

Comment: You really ought to get in the habit of looking at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout) for Javascript functions you are using for the first time before you come asking here.  If you've followed the advice there and still have trouble, then you can demonstrate what you've learned and describe where you got stuck when you ask here.

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass the *timeoutID*. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout.

So as not to pollute the global scope (with `timer`, `run` and `stop`), I'd wrap everything in jQuery's ready handler and use it to bind the event handlers

```
<form id="fid">
    <input type="text" id="input_type">
</form>
```

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var myplace = $('#myplace'), form = $('#fid'), timer = null;

    $('#input_type').on({
        keypress: function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        },
        keyup: function() {
            myplace.hide();
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                $.post('xx.php', form.serialize(), function(data) {
                    myplace.html(data).show();
                });
            }, 3000);
        }
    });
});
```